# SharePoint 2010 CAML from BIDS, using VS 2008

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SSRS, SQL Server 2008, not R2, and SharePoint 2010 on separate servers.  I'm trying to develop a couple of reports against 2 lists that are related.

I created a Shared Data Source for the lists using the _vti_bin/lists.aspx (type XML), then created a DataSource that uses the shared data source reference.  I have also created 2 DataSets, one for each list using CAML.

For both DataSets, I am getting returns but I'm missing fields...

Maybe it's the DataSet CAML statement??? Or would it be something else entirely?

Here is my CAML statement:

```
    <Query>

        <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>

        <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">

            <Parameters>

               <Parameter Name="listName">

                    <DefaultValue>{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}</DefaultValue>
               </Parameter>


               <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>

            </Parameters>

        </Method>

    </Query>
```

Any suggestions on a better way to do this are also acceptable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After your:

```
<Query></Query>
```

you should have a:

```
<Field>
  <Field Name="FieldName">...</Field>
</Field>
```

for each field that you need.

Hope this helps,

Chris

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  But now I'm stuck on how to get the actual names of the fields?

Comment: I found I am able to do this using field names:

        <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">GetListItemsResponse/GetListItemsResult/listitems/data/row{@Column1,@Column2,@Column3,@Column4,@column5,@column6,@column7}</ElementPath>

One thing I was stuck on is that the @ MUST BE INCLUDED prior to the field name.  In my case it looks like @ows_FieldName

Comment: yes most parameters in ssrs use the @ParamName syntax, so is this question resolved? can you mark it as an answer?